# Download rate limiting C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to download a file from a c# application but, I'd like to be able to limit the network bandwidth that I use, from the client side how can I limit the download speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx)

(more [here](http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/))

Comment: No other options offered and this looks good so I'll accept it.