# Winsock rate limiting

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, winsock

Are there any facilities to enable me to limit bandwidth usage (rx) when utilizing Winsock (TCP)?

I have looked into QoS but, for one it seems overly complex and secondly much of the discussion revolves around a feature (RSVP) that isn't even available on post-Win2k platforms.

(Only interested in native solutions; no .NET or the like)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000719/what-api-of-linux-windows-corresponds-to-limiting-network-download-upload-spee

Comment: See my answer on the link to the question I called out as a dupe. You can try QOS, but you may find it easier to just do your own throttling by controlling the rate at which winsock send() and recv() calls are made.

Comment: Yeah that was my alternate plan however it seems a tad inelegant as opposed to simply modifying the TCP window directly.

Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Leaky bucket algorithm + Sleep?

Comment: @Damon Something similiar. Sleep's accuracy is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Set very small socket send and receive buffer sizes, such as 1k or less if the platform will allow it. That limits the bandwidth-delay product, which in turn limits the receive window, which in turn limits the throughput.

Comment: I'm not using socket-level buffering.

Comment: @Matt.J Yes you are. You can't help it. The kernel provides a socket send buffer and a socket receive buffer.

Comment: Yes, what's your point? Your solution relies on socket-level buffering which I just pointed out is disabled; access to the internal buffers in AFD are not accessible.

Comment: @Matt.J It isn't 'disabled'. It is an integral part of TCP, defined in the RFCs. An implementation of TCP could not function without send and receive buffers. You can control them via `setsockopt()` at the C level and via various higher level APIs. I don't see what AFD has to do with it.

Comment: Seems like your understanding is limited to abstract models; I will clarify:
SO_SNDBUF=0
SO_RCVBUF=0

How does your solution fit in now?

Comment: @Matt.J I still don't know what AFD has to do with it, although AFD certainly maintains send and receive buffers. But you said Winsock above, and Winsock has socket buffers too. Perhaps you need to clarify your question so that mortals who only understand 'abstract models' can actually understand it. Most of what you have just written is brand new to this thread. But if you already have buffer sizes of zero, somehow, you are already, somehow, adopting my suggestion. If that isn't adequate rate-limiting you will certainly need another solution on top.

Comment: It was established in my original reply as to why your solution is not suitable and if you could answer my above question maybe we'd get somewhere.